# UIAlertController is covered by a view on window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

When I add a UIView to keyWindow,the alertController is covered by the view.Here is the code.

```
- (void)touch {
    UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIView *viewhaha = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    viewhaha.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [currentWindow addSubview:viewhaha];

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"123" message:@"123" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"123" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    }];

    [alertController addAction:action1];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

and here is the Image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyKVM.png)

Do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a view to the `window` will cover any view that isn't also added to the `window` and placed on top of it. The window layer is the uppermost layer that you can add something to. If you want the `UIView` to be placed underneath the `UIAlertViewController` you must add that `UIView` to a subview of the `UIViewController`'s `.view` that you are presenting the `UIAlertController` within.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with  @Brandon A 's answer window is topmost layer and it will cover all background views

I have attached screen shot that will  help you to understand

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add new UIView to your view controller instead of key window. Just change line 4

```
[currentWindow addSubview:viewhaha];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:viewhaha];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touch {    
UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];

UIView *viewhaha = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
viewhaha.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[currentTopVC.view addSubview:viewhaha];

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"123" message:@"123" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"123" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
}];

[alertController addAction:action1];
[currentTopVC presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

}

```
- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController {
UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
while (topVC.presentedViewController)
{
    topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
}
return topVC;
```

}